# geoserver upload kml no format

Tags: api, geoserver

I'm using the API of the geoserver ([link](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/importer/rest_reference.html)) to upload a new kml file to mu local machine using a post request to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/imports with the following json

```
{
   "import": {
      "targetWorkspace": {
         "workspace": {
            "name": "sample"
         }
      },
      "targetStore": {
         "dataStore": {
            "name": "sample"
         }
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "file",
        "file": "/data/sample_dir/sample.kml"
      }
   }
}
```

I should get the data type and the state as ready on the response according to the API documentation but I'm getting a pending and no file format.
Response:

```
{
    "import": {
        "id": 23,
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/imports/23",
        "state": "PENDING",
        "archive": false,
        "targetWorkspace": {
            "workspace": {
                "name": "sample"
            }
        },
        "targetStore": {
            "dataStore": {
                "name": "sample",
                "type": "Directory of spatial files (shapefiles)"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "file",
            "format": null,
            "file": "sample.kml"
        },
        "tasks": []
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me the code you used to upload to GeoServer? I'm having a hard time trying to get the POST request right.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the geoserver don't accept the relative path like it says on the API documentation.
If instead of:

```
"data": {
        "type": "file",
        "file": "./data/sample_dir/sample.kml"
      }
```

I use

```
"data": {
        "type": "file",
        "file": "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/sample_dir/sample.kml"
      }
```

on the request it works fine.

Comment: since your file starts with a `/` it is not relative!